# MariaDB MySQL Won't Start

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I am in a bind, today our server with the MySQL Server went down and we are having trouble getting it back up. Only change to the system is that we upgraded the ram from 2gb to 4gb. Everything else on the system is working except the MySQL Server. I have included the most recent error section from the error log. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: This is running on a Windows 2008 R2 Server 64bit.

Error Log:
[image]

Comment: Are you getting after that also error messages about encrypted blocks, without actually using encryption? If you are, and you are running a version below 10.1.19, try to upgrade. There was a bug which was fixed in 10.1.19: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10394 .

Comment: have you tried starting with innodb_force_recovery parameter by setting it's value and then check, moreover a quick fix may be sacrificing your log files by moving them to some other location as they would be re-created during the start but do read MySQL documentation for both approaches.. hope it helps.